# Question about white-box rsa algorithm

Tags: rsa, public-key, white-box

I found a scheme for [white-box RSA](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10726108B2/en?q=white%20box&inventor=Jan%20Hoogerbrugge&oq=inventor:(Jan%20Hoogerbrugge)%20white%20box). It seems to protect the input and output of modular operations.
I'm curious about how to analyze the security of this solution.
Does anybody know anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

That is a weird patent.  The title says "RSA"; however the claims are strictly for elliptic curve operations (and while the description is more general, it is written at such a high level that it's hard at times to see what it's actually trying to say).

The ideas in the claims appear to be mostly blinding the ECC projective coordinates; this idea was published by Coron back in 1999.

In the end, the ideas behind the "white-box" parts of this idea appear to depend on:

- You having a compiler that obfuscates the output, that is, "the method of obscuring software code is carried out by a compiler".  That strikes me as a cheat - if you had a compiler that generated white-box-quality output, why do you need this idea?
- An assumption that "none of the splitting secret multiplicative values and the secret splitting additive value are observable to an attacker"; that appears to be inconsistent with the assumptions of "white-box", where the attacker can observe everything.

Color me unimpressed (and it's hard to analyze the security, as it depends so crucially on the above two assumptions)